# Given an integer of the form: $2^j*3^k$ - is there a way to quickly find j and k?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-functions

Suppose you have a number that you know is of the form: $2^j*3^k$ (j,k are positive integers). Is there a way to quickly (ie constant,linear time) find what j and k are?

Basically is there a faster way to determine what j and k are without repeatedly dividing by 2 (or 3) until you hit a get a real number?

Comment: Keep dividing two from the number while the number is even. The number of times you divide two is the $j$ and $k$ becomes $\log_3{x}$ where $x$ is the number after you finished dividing the twos

Comment: @JadenLee: That’s not constant time, however.

Comment: @JadenLee - yes that would be the straightforward approach.  But what I was wondering about was if there is a solution that does not involved looping?

Comment: How can you read $N$ in constant time, let alone do any computation on it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "you have number"? Details like this matter if you want to "have a way to quickly (ie constant time)...". Oh, and exactly what kind of operations are you allowed to use and what is their time complexity?

Comment: @Somos - 'you have a number' means that someone constructed this integer in the form $2^j*3^k$ and gave it to you.  The job is to determine j and k.

Answer (score 1):

Quickly, as in polynomial in $j$ and $k$? Yes. In constant time? That is an easy No. Even checking whether a number is dividable by 3 involves adding up all the digits and seeing if they are dividable by 3. This cannot be done in constant time.

In fact, for every integer $\ell$ there are an infinite number of combinations $(j,k)$ s.t. $2^j3^k$ is the same mod $10^{\ell}$ so looking at the first $\ell$ digits will not help.